# Converting current VBS script to include a table

Tags: vbscript

I am in the process of making an VBS script that pulls info from AD and makes a nice signature in AD full of information to be included in the signature.

Now the code i have works perfectly and does what is required.

This is the code

```
    On Error Resume Next

Set objSysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strUser = objSysInfo.UserName
Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & strUser)

strName = objUser.FullName
strFname = objUser.FirstName
strLname = objUser.LastName
strTitle = objUser.title
strCompany = objUser.company
strCred = objUser.info
strStreet = objUser.StreetAddress
strLocation = objUser.l
strCity = objUser.st
strPostCode = objUser.PostalCode
strPhone = objUser.TelephoneNumber
strMobile = objUser.Mobile
strFax = objUser.FacsimileTelephoneNumber
strEmail = objUser.mail
strWeb = objuser.wWWHomePage

Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add()
Set objSelection = objWord.Selection
Set objSelection1 = objWord.Selection1
Set objEmailOptions = objWord.EmailOptions
Set objSignatureObject = objEmailOptions.EmailSignature
Set objSignatureEntries = objSignatureObject.EmailSignatureEntries

'Hyperlink Style
objDoc.Styles("Hyperlink").Font.Color = RGB(255, 102, 0)
objDoc.Styles("Hyperlink").Font.Size = 9
objDoc.Styles("Hyperlink").Font.Name = "Calibri"

'Kind Regards
objSelection.Font.Color = RGB(64,64,64)
objSelection.Font.Name = "Calibri"
objSelection.Font.Size = 12
objSelection.TypeParagraph()
objSelection.TypeText "Kind regards,"
objSelection.TypeText Chr(11)

'FirstName LastName
objSelection.Font.Name = "Calibri"
objSelection.Font.Size = 11
objSelection.Font.Color = RGB(64,64,64)
objSelection.TypeText Chr(11)
objSelection.Font.Bold = True
if (strFname) Then objSelection.TypeText strFname
if (strLname) Then objSelection.TypeText "  " & strLname & Chr(11)
objSelection.Font.Bold = False

'Job Title
objSelection.Font.Name = "Calibri"
objSelection.Font.Size = 11
objSelection.Font.Color = RGB(64,64,64)
if (strTitle) Then objSelection.TypeText strTitle & Chr(11)
'Company Name
objSelection.Font.Name = "Calibri"
objSelection.Font.Size = 11
objSelection.Font.Color = RGB(64,64,64)
if (strCompany) Then objSelection.TypeText strCompany & Chr(11)

'Swann Logo
Set objShape = objSelection.InLineShapes.AddPicture("http://www.swanngroupltd.com/sig500.jpg")
objSelection.TypeText "   "
objSelection.Font.Size = 2
objSelection.TypeText Chr(11)
objSelection.Font.Size = 9

'Variables from AD
objSelection.Font.Name = "Calibri"
objSelection.Font.Size = 9
objSelection.Font.Color = RGB(64,64,64)
if (strPhone) Then objSelection.TypeText "t: " & strPhone & Space(2)
if (strMobile) Then objSelection.TypeText "m: " & strMobile & Space(2)
if (strFax) Then objSelection.TypeText "Fax: " & strFax & Chr(11)
'Email
objSelection.TypeText Chr(11)
objselection.typeText "e: " & strEmailTEXT 
Set objLink = objSelection.Hyperlinks.Add(objSelection.Range, "mailto: " & strEmail, , , strEmail)
objSelection1.Font.Color = RGB(255,102,0)
objSelection.TypeText Chr(11)
'Variables from AD
objSelection.Font.Name = "Calibri"
objSelection.Font.Size = 9
objSelection.Font.Color = RGB(64,64,64)
if (strStreet) Then objSelection.TypeText "" & strStreet & Space(1)
if (strLocation) Then objSelection.TypeText ", " & strLocation & Space(1)
if (strCity) Then objSelection.TypeText ", " & strCity & Space(1)
if (strPostCode) Then objSelection.TypeText ", " & strPostCode & Chr(11)
'Company Registration
objSelection.Font.Name = "Calibri"
objSelection.Font.Size = 9
objSelection.Font.Color = RGB(64,64,64)
objSelection.TypeText "Company Registration No: 1164271 VAT Registered No: 104453212"

'Please Visit Us
objSelection.TypeText Chr(11)

objSelection.Font.Name = "Calibri"
objSelection.Font.Size = 9
objSelection.TypeText Chr(11)
objSelection.TypeText "Please visit us at:"
objSelection.TypeText Chr(11)

'URL1
objSelection.Font.Name = "Calibri"
objSelection.Font.Bold = False
objSelection.Font.Size = "9"
objSelection.Font.Color = RGB(255,102,0)
objLink = objSelection.Hyperlinks.Add(objSelection.Range,"http://www.swanngroupltd.com",,"Swann Group Ltd", "www.swanngroupltd.com")
objSelection.TypeText Space(2)

'URL2
objSelection.Font.Name = "Calibri"
objSelection.Font.Bold = False
objSelection.Font.Size = "9"
objLink = objSelection.Hyperlinks.Add(objSelection.Range,"http://www.towermaster.co.uk",,"Towermaster", "www.towermaster.co.uk")
objSelection.TypeText Space(2)

'URL3
objSelection.Font.Name = "Calibri"
objSelection.Font.Bold = False
objSelection.Font.Size = "9"
objLink = objSelection.Hyperlinks.Add(objSelection.Range,"http://www.swanndirect.com",,"Swann Direct", "www.swanndirect.com")
objSelection.Font.Color = RGB(255,102,0)
objSelection.TypeText Chr(11)
objSelection.TypeText Chr(11)

'Towermaster
Set objLink = objSelection.Hyperlinks.Add(objSelection.InlineShapes.AddPicture("http://www.swanngroupltd.com/towermaster.jpg"), "http://www.towermaster.co.uk",,,"")

objSelection.TypeText Chr(11)
objSelection.TypeText Chr(11)

'Accreditation Logo
Set objLink = objSelection.Hyperlinks.Add(objSelection.InlineShapes.AddPicture("http://www.swanngroupltd.com/Sig-Acc.png"), "http://www.swanngroupltd.com",,,"")


'Disclaimer
objSelection.TypeText Chr(11)
objSelection.Font.Name = "Calibri"
objSelection.Font.Size = 9
objSelection.Font.Color = RGB(64,64,64)
objSelection.TypeText Chr(11)
objSelection.TypeText "Please consider the environment before printing this email"
objSelection.TypeText Chr(11)
objSelection.TypeText "The information transmitted in this e-mail and its attachments is intended only for the person or entity to which it is addressed and may contain confidential and/or legally privileged material.  Any review, retransmission, dissemination or other use of, or taking of any action in reliance upon, this information by persons or entities other than the intended recipient is prohibited.  If you receive this in error, please contact the sender and delete the material from any computer.  We will not accept responsibility for any commitments made by our employees outside the scope of our business and offer no warrant to the accuracy or completeness of such information."

Set objSelection = objDoc.Range()

'Name of Signature in Outlook
objSignatureEntries.Add "Swann Formal Signature", objSelection
objSignatureObject.NewMessageSignature = "Swann Formal signature"
objSignatureObject.ReplyMessageSignature = "Swann Formal Signature"

objDoc.Saved = True
objWord.Quit
```

Now i have been asked to change the layout to something like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6vmC.png

As you can see at the bottom is the shape of the table,.

How do i convert my current code into this table?
I send thanks in advance for anyone that can help with this, as VBS isnt my strong point and i have got this far..

Comment: Open Word, enable the macro recorder, create a table with the right number of rows and columns, stop the macro recorder, look at the generated VBA code. Transfer the code to your VBS.

Comment: it doesnt work VBA code for an outlook signature, tried that already

Comment: I did not say "copy the code", I said "transfer it". That means you must make the necessary changes. The generated VBA macro just gives you an idea how to create a table in Word.

Comment: i seem unable to convert it, just doesnt seem to work. Is there someone i can go that will help get it converted>?